# How to detect Face and Smile & Face matching in Android?

Tags: android, face-recognition

I want to know following things is possible on Android or not.

1. Pick a photo and detects faces and show rectangle, and detect smile of each face and show smile percentage of each.
2. Pick a photo from photo library and show faces. if you click faces, it search all photo library and show list of possible same person.

Answer (score 6):

Let's take thing in order :

- Detecting the face : Android seems to be able to do that, through the [FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) class. Read the doc to know how to do that.
- Detecting smiles and/or similar people : such a function is not integrated in `FaceDetector`. However, this is a matter of face recognition, and many work has been done in research on this subject. A Google research should point you to the theoric papers relative to that, but I'm not sure they will all have an implementation.

**EDIT** : the main image processing library used by researchers for this kind of subjects is [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). You can find a Java wrapper for it [here](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/).

Answer (score 1):

Extending Valentin Rocher's answer: I think in a limited way you can achieve it by doing following:

1. Get array of FaceDetector.Face objects in the photo using [findFaces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html)()
2. Iterate through the array of FaceDetector.Face objects, you can use following APIs and compare (i.e. fix one face as a reference and compare it with other in the array to find similarity/closeness)

   confidence()
   eyesDistance()
   getMidPoint()
   pose()

Comment: That's a way to do it, but two people can have the same eyes distance and/or midpoint, and be two different people

Comment: Yes, very true. Image processing is inherently very subjective. By comparing more parameters (confidence, eye distance, mid point, pose, etc.) as listed above, one can reduce the possibility which you rightly commented.

Comment: Android phone is a higher-end embedded system, and implementation of complex image processing algorithms is possible. However keeping in mind the capability of phone's processor, we need to balance efficiency and performance of the resulting application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a google example for detecting smile. Please check:

[FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker)

It is Android Vision API and requires Android Play Services SDK level 26 or greater.